# htacess rule for files - starts with and ends with

Tags: .htaccess

For some reason I can't get this rule to work
(starts with page and ends with .swf)
I want to deny these files:
page01.swf
page02.swf

```
<Files ~ "^(page)\.swf$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

tried this too:

```
<FilesMatch "^(page)\.swf$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use number sequence in regex pattern to match pageXX.swf(XX denotes any number). Check this code below

```
<FilesMatch "^(page[0-9]+)\.swf$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

**UPDATED**
It match any character(both small or caps) or number. if you want to match only small letter. Remove A-Z from regex.

```
<FilesMatch "^(page[0-9a-zA-Z]+)\.swf$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: That looks good. Can I do this to encompass any characters in between?

    <FilesMatch "^(page*)\.swf$">
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </FilesMatch>

Comment: @Wiggonator if My answer solve your problem. Please mark my answer accepted. it will help others looking for similar problem on StackOverflow.